# What can you say about $f$ and $g$ in the case that $fg$ is 1) Injective, 2) Surjective - Cohn - Classic Algebra Page 15

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> **Question:** Are my proofs below valid?

In both cases we are using: $f:A\to B, g: B\to C$

Notation of your type converted: $(g\circ f)(x)=g(f(x))=xfg$

---

If $fg$ is injective what can be said about $f$ and $g$?

If $fg$ is injective then $f$ is injective:

**Proof:**

$(x_1fg = x_2fg \implies x_1=x_2)$

$x_1fg=x_2fg$ is clearly true when $x_1f=x_2f$

Which requires $x_1=x_2$, hence $f$ is injective.

If $f$ were not injective, then $x_1fg\ne x_2fg$

$\blacksquare$

---

If $fg$ is surjective what can be said about $f$ and $g$?

If $fg$ is surjective then $g$ is surjective:

**Proof:**

$(\forall c\in C)(\exists a\in A) |( a(fg))=c$

This means for $g$ every element must have had been mapped to. How can this be proved Mathematically?

well $(af)g=c$ is surjective, hence $(af)=(b\in B)$ and $bg=c$

$(\forall c\in g)(\exists b\in B)|(bg=c)$

Hence $g$ is surjective.

$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If $fg$ is injective what can be said about $f$ and $g$?
>   $(x_1fg = x_2fg \implies x_1=x_2)$
>   This is clearly true if $x_1f=x_2f$
>   Which requires $x_1=x_2$, hence $f$ is injective.
>   If $f$ were not injective, then $x_1fg\ne x_2fg$
>   $\blacksquare$

I don't follow your "if $fg$ is injective..." proof. What is "clearly true" if $x_1 f= x_2 f$ (I am guessing $x_1 fg= x_2fg$) and why does that require $x_1=x_2$. And if $f$ were not injective I am sure there would be plenty of $x_1,x_2$ so that $x_1fg = x_2fg$.

Your surjectivity proof looks fine.

Also I would say what you are proving before proving it when writing it up.

Comment: Good point on the injectivity proof having flaws. I will work on it and amend a new attempt to the bottom of the answer(Rather than editing the wrong one)

Comment: Question^ rather

Comment: @Committingtoachallenge You basically have it now and adding the small change I see you added made it far more clear than it was before. Are you trying to prove injectivity two different ways? It looks like you basically have two proofs which may have also been a tad confusing.

Comment: Oh I felt like they were both required, are you saying that the last second of that proof could be it's own proof by contradiction? I only put that there to cover all bases

Comment: Yup. If you expanded out why the statements you claim are true (especially the $x_1fg \neq x_2fg$ proof, I think I know what you are getting at but you are missing details) it would be more clear that you proved that $f$ is injective two different ways.